# Composite of two algebraic extensions is algebraic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L,F$ be extensions of the field $K$ and are contained in a common field. Prove that, if $L$ and $F$ are algebraic extensions over $K$ then $LF$ is also a algebraic extension over $K$.

Help me a hint.

Thank for any insight.

Comment: @ chuyenvvien84:  what is $LF$?  How is it defined?

Comment: @RobertLewis As $L$ and $F$ are contained in a common field, say $E$, the field $LF$ is usually the subfield of $E$ generated by the elements of $L$ and $F$.

Comment: @Pece: Of course.

Comment: @ Pece:  so it is the usual thing about the smallest subfield of $E$ containing $L$ and $F$, then, right?

Comment: @RobertLewis: That's right

Comment: Help me. please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $\alpha$ is in $LF$. Then it can be expressed in terms of some elements $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_r$ of $L$ and $\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_s$ of $F$. So it's in the extension of $K$ generated by $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_r,\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_s$. That's a finite extension of $K$, so $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$.

Comment: Thank you for your support

Comment: I think it is not correct if neither of the extensions is finite

Comment: @Astrid, you think my argument is not correct? or you think the statement we are asked to prove is not correct?

Comment: Well, now I realized I'm confused , why the smallest subfield containing $L$ and $F$ coincides with the field generated by $L$ and $F$?

Comment: The field generated by $L$ and $F$ is a field containing both $L$ and $F$. Among all fields containing both $L$ and $F$, the smallest would be the one they generate.

Comment: Thank you , now everything is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof, which I think is clearer:
Let $E$ be the algebraic closure of $K$ in $LF$, namely $ E=\{ a\in LF \mid   a    \,\textrm{is algebraic over}\,K\}$. It is easy to prove that $E$ is a field, the proof one can find in any algebraic textbook. Since $L\subseteq LF$, and $L$ is algebraic  over $K$, so we have $L\subseteq E$.  $F\subseteq E$ can be proved  in the same way. So we have $LF\subseteq E$. But on the other hand $E\subseteq LF$. We can say that $E=LF$, which means that $LF$ is algebraic over $K$.