# If L and M are algebraic over K then so is LM

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Edit: My question was linked with the following question and closed as duplicate:[$M /K \land L /K$ algebraic $\implies ML/K$ algebraic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324976/m-k-land-l-k-algebraic-implies-ml-k-algebraic)

> But if one just sees and compares the statements in the two questions, it is easy to see that the both are not same. So, kindly reopen it.

This question was asked in my abstract algebra mid term exam ( in November) and I was uunable to solve this particular question.

> Let L and M be intermediate fields in the extension $K\subset F$. Then if L and M are algebraic over K then so is LM.

I was unable to use the fact that L and M are given algebraic over K. So, I revised through my notebook today also but still couldn't  proceed. I need help in this so can you please outline main details of solution?

For Theory I have been Using Textbook by Hernstein.

Answer (score 0):

If $M$ is algebraic over $K$, it is for sure also algebraic over $L$. So $LM=L(M)$ is algebraic over $L$ (since it is generated by algebraic elements). Since $L/K$ is algebraic and the property 'algebraic' is transitive we see that $LM/K$ is algebraic.
Another way to see the claim is by noting that the elements of $LM$ are quotients of sums of products of elements in $L$ and $M$. And the product/sum/quotient of algebraic elements is algebraic.